# PHP -- Unsyntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO) on line 58

Tags: php

```
  else if (isset($id) && isset($street_address) && isset($price)  ){
  echo '<p>Are you sure you want to delete the following product?</p>';
  echo '<p><strong>Street Address: </strong>' . $street_address '<br/><strong>Price: </strong>' . $price .;
  //  '<br /><strong>Price: </strong>' . $pPrice . '</p>';
   echo '<form method="post" action="removehome.php">'; <-- (line 58)
```

I've tryed adding an ending semicolon to the line above but end up getting an "unexpected ";" error. How do I fix this?

Comment: extra dot..............

Comment: problem is here `</strong>' . $price .;`. You use a . after the `$price`.

Comment: pro tip: if error says line 58, be sure to look at line 57 and above

Comment: @Dagon Yes, there are way too many dots in your comment ;)

Comment: @Rizier123 I've gone dotty

Comment: Thank you very much. I somehow overlooked at. Hopefully this question can help someone else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here `</strong>' . $price .;`. You use a extra `.` after the `$price`.

```
else if(isset($id) && isset($street_address) && isset($price)){
  echo '<p>Are you sure you want to delete the following product?</p>';
  echo '<p><strong>Street Address: </strong>'.$street_address.'<br/><strong>Price: </strong>'.$price;  
  echo '<form method="post" action="removehome.php">';
```